# Define a gridbox from spatial (lat/long) data and extract average value in R

Tags: r, spatial, netcdf

I would like to compute the spatial average over a region of data that I define, by defining a longitude/latitude gridbox.

The data I have is ECMWF Sea-ice data, so it's spatio-temporal data for each .75x.75 lon/lat coordinate over the whole Northern Hemisphere. I've changed the data from NetCDF format into an R dataframe, so the head(var.df) looks like this with columns: Date, longitude, latitude, value

```
            date_time lon   lat ci
1 2016-01-01 18:00:00   0 87.75  1
2 2016-01-02 18:00:00   0 87.75  1
3 2016-01-03 18:00:00   0 87.75  1
4 2016-01-04 18:00:00   0 87.75  1
5 2016-01-05 18:00:00   0 87.75  1
6 2016-01-06 18:00:00   0 87.75  1
```

There is therefore a value for each lon/lat coordinate across the northern hemisphere (df is ordered by date, rather than lon for some reason).

How would I extract the spatial area that I want i.e.

```
BK <- subset(var.df,lon <= 30 & lon >= 105 & lat >= 70 & lat <= 80)
```

and then average all the values that fall within that area, for each timestep (day)?  So I'd have the mean of a gridbox that I define.

Thanks in advance, I hope this wasn't phrased terribly.

**Update**

Using GGamba's suggested code below, I got the following output, with multiple values for the same day so it hadn't averaged the whole region by timeslice.

```
             date_time  binlat  binlon      mean
                <dttm>  <fctr>  <fctr>     <dbl>
1  2016-01-01 18:00:00 [80,90)  [0,10) 0.4200042
2  2016-01-01 18:00:00 [80,90) [10,20) 0.4503899
3  2016-01-01 18:00:00 [80,90) [20,30) 0.5614429
4  2016-01-01 18:00:00 [80,90) [30,40) 0.6118528
5  2016-01-01 18:00:00 [80,90) [40,50) 0.5809092
6  2016-01-01 18:00:00 [80,90) [50,60) 0.5617919
7  2016-01-01 18:00:00 [80,90) [60,70) 0.6071370
8  2016-01-01 18:00:00 [80,90) [70,80) 0.6011818
9  2016-01-01 18:00:00 [80,90) [80,90] 0.5442770
10 2016-01-01 18:00:00 [80,90)      NA 0.4120862
# ... with 610 more rows
```

I also had to add na.rm = TRUE to the mean() function at the end, as the averages were NA.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` we can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(binlon = cut(lon, seq(from = min(lon), to = max(lon), by = .75), include.lowest = T, right = F),
           binlat = cut(lat, seq(from = min(lat), to = max(lat), by = .75), include.lowest = T, right = F)) %>% 
    group_by(date_time, binlat, binlon) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(ci))
```

#### Data:

```
structure(list(date_time = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2016-01-01 18:00:00", 
"2016-01-02 18:00:00", "2016-01-03 18:00:00", "2016-01-04 18:00:00", 
"2016-01-05 18:00:00", "2016-01-06 18:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
    lon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 90L), lat = c(0, 87.75, 87.75, 
    87.75, 87.75, 90), ci = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("date_time", 
"lon", "lat", "ci"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

#### Results:

```
#             date_time      binlat    binlon  mean
#                <fctr>      <fctr>    <fctr> <dbl>
# 1 2016-01-01 18:00:00    [0,0.75)  [0,0.75)     1
# 2 2016-01-02 18:00:00 [87.8,88.5)  [0,0.75)     1
# 3 2016-01-03 18:00:00 [87.8,88.5)  [0,0.75)     1
# 4 2016-01-04 18:00:00 [87.8,88.5)  [0,0.75)     1
# 5 2016-01-05 18:00:00 [87.8,88.5)  [0,0.75)     1
# 6 2016-01-06 18:00:00   [89.2,90] [89.2,90]     1
# 6 2016-01-06 18:00:00 [80,90) [0,10)     1
```

This create two new columns binning `lat` & `lon` into bins defined into the `cut` function.
Then group by `date_time` and the new columns and calculate the `ci` mean on the group.

Of course you should adapt the `cut` function to suit your need.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, GGamba

Just wanted to know why there are 3 values inside the cut() function (80,180,10), what is the final (10) value for?

Also, it didn't return a single value for each day - I've uploaded the output in original question.

Comment: For the first question: the 3 values are inside the `seq` function, it creates a sequence from the first value to the last, stepping by the third. `cut` divides the variable into bins defined by this sequence. cfr `?cut` and `?seq`.

Comment: As for the second, I probably don't understand what you need. I thought you needed an average for each 'square' and each day. The code assumes that only one measurement is taken each day, at 18:00, as you did not specify otherwise. Are there multiple observation per day per location?

Comment: Yes - apologies - absolutely the fault of my explanation.

It's gridded data, so one value (ci) for each lon/lat coordinate across the northern hemisphere, so there's only 1 observation per day but across many locations given that it's .75x.75 resolution. 

I just need to get a single average for the entire gridbox, the coordinates of which I define.   Is there a way I could upload the data here, or a subset of the data?

Comment: Change the values in the `cut` function to suit you need. I updated the answer to some more sensible values, but I encourage you to read `?seq` and `?cut` to learn how they work.

Comment: Use `dput(df)` to share a minimal example of your data